# grails - spring-security-core secure-channel causing redirect loop (on Heroku)

Tags: grails

I'm using spring-security-core and have setup the secure-channel capabilities, which work fine on my development machine.  I've got the following in Config.groovy

```
grails.plugins.springsecurity.secureChannel.definition = [
   '/order/checkout': 'REQUIRES_SECURE_CHANNEL',
   '/order/paymentComplete': 'REQUIRES_INSECURE_CHANNEL'
]
```

Also, deploying to Heroku the associated order processing works fine, **as long** as I comment out the above lines.  As soon as I put them back in, I get:

[image: redirect error]

I see many requests come in on the server, and the Firebug net view shows:

[image: redirect network view]

I've got the PiggyBack SSL added on to Heroku, and I'm able to specify an https://... address to navigate to other parts of the site, in which case the browser stays in SSL mode.  But if I access the

```
https:/www.momentumnow.co/order/checkout
```

address directly, I get the same redirect loop problem.  Do you know what the problem is or how I can debug this further.  If the latter, would you please update the comment area, and I will respond with updates to the problem area.  Thanks

PiggyBack SSL [documentation](https://addons.heroku.com/ssl) indicates:

"Piggyback SSL will allow you to use https://yourapp.heroku.com, since it uses the *.heroku.com certification. You don't need to buy or configure a certificate, it just works. https://yourcustomdomain.com will work, but it will produce a warning in the browser."

I'll probably switch to another mode as I add a certificate, however that does not seem to be the problem, based on the previous statement.

---

On the server, I get:

[image]

Comment: Hi Ray, did you ever get an answer to this?  I'm having a similar issue in Clojure on Heroku.

Comment: I found a solution in this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10137761/grails-application-on-heroku-with-ssl

Answer (score 6):

You need to fix the values for the ports since they default to 8080 and 8443. See the section on Channel Security in the docs - http://grails-plugins.github.com/grails-spring-security-core/docs/manual/ - about the `grails.plugins.springsecurity.portMapper.httpPort` and `grails.plugins.springsecurity.portMapper.httpsPort` config attributes.

Comment: Ah - wonderful.  Thanks pointing out the general issue (and also for showing me where to find the answer).  Much appreciated.   Separately, can you tell me if I should continue on with spring-security-UI pulled out (and add my own registration code) to work on Heroku?  (this is the problem with the plugins used by spring-security-ui apparently incompatible with the Heroku plugin).  Thanks.

Comment: Hmm.  Searched Heroku for SSL port info, found none, and so I used 80 for the httpPort and 443 for the httpsPort.  Still get same error (except I see port 443 in the requests).  Also, when I just do https://site/,  I can see the remote port is 443 in the packets sent back and forth, so this appears to be the right port.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else stumbling into this (as I did) the problem is that your app doesn't actually receive the request as HTTPS. Rather, Heroku replaces the HTTPS with a "X-Forwarded-Proto" header. Spring-security's HTTPS redirection is then putting you into an infinite redirect loop because it *always* detects the request as HTTP.

You can write your own `SecureChannelProcessor` to deal with this:

```
public class HerokuSecureChannelProcessor extends SecureChannelProcessor {

    @Override
    public void decide(FilterInvocation invocation, Collection<ConfigAttribute> config)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        Assert.isTrue((invocation != null) && (config != null),
                "Nulls cannot be provided");

        for (ConfigAttribute attribute : config) {
            if (supports(attribute)) {
                String header = invocation.getHttpRequest().getHeader("X-Forwarded-Proto");
                if(header == null){
                    // proceed normally
                    if (!invocation.getHttpRequest().isSecure()) {
                        getEntryPoint().commence(invocation.getRequest(), invocation.getResponse());
                    }
                } else {
                    // use heroku header instead
                    if("http".equals(header)) {
                        getEntryPoint().commence(invocation.getRequest(), invocation.getResponse());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```