# Grails on Heroku - spring security core secureChannel.definition causes redirect loop

Tags: grails, ssl, heroku, spring-security

There were a handful of questions last year around this same topic:

[Grails application on Heroku with ssl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10137761/grails-application-on-heroku-with-ssl)

[grails - spring-security-core secure-channel causing redirect loop (on Heroku)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9090709/grails-spring-security-core-secure-channel-causing-redirect-loop-on-heroku)

[grails -  simple App to test spring-security-core secure-channel on Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9105084/grails-simple-app-to-test-spring-security-core-secure-channel-on-heroku)

But no satisfactory answers seemed to crop up at the time.

I'm running a 2.24 Grails app on heroku, using the Spring security plugin (1.2.7.3).

Attempting to use:

```
 grails.plugins.springsecurity.secureChannel.definition = [
 '/myAccount/**':         'REQUIRES_SECURE_CHANNEL',
 ]
```

causes a redirect loop to occur for that url mapping.

My Coonfig.groovy contains:

```
  grails.plugins.springsecurity.secureChannel.useHeaderCheckChannelSecurity = true#
```

In one of the questions linked above, Burt mentioned that

```
 grails.plugins.springsecurity.portMapper.httpPort
 grails.plugins.springsecurity.portMapper.httpPort
```

probably need to be changed, but I can't find any documentation anywhere to sugegst what ports should be used for Heroku - i've tried using 80 for http and 443 for https, but get the same problem.

Has anyone succesfully got this working at any point?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like this was down to The Spring Security plugin using the wrong case for 'x-forwarded-proto' when

```
 grails.plugins.springsecurity.secureChannel.useHeaderCheckChannelSecurity = true
```

is set.

Adding this to my config.groovy solved the issue

```
grails.plugins.springsecurity.secureChannel.useHeaderCheckChannelSecurity = true
grails.plugins.springsecurity.portMapper.httpPort = 80
grails.plugins.springsecurity.portMapper.httpsPort = 443
grails.plugins.springsecurity.secureChannel.secureHeaderName = 'X-FORWARDED-PROTO'
grails.plugins.springsecurity.secureChannel.secureHeaderValue = 'http'

grails.plugins.springsecurity.secureChannel.insecureHeaderName = 'X-FORWARDED-PROTO'
grails.plugins.springsecurity.secureChannel.insecureHeaderValue = 'https'
```

Comment: I'm using Grails 3.2.8 and this solution solved the https loop problem for me.